# Use jquery inside php foreach into html (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, loops

**The main issue is my first row at the table (column:waktu) has no jquery countdown time**

Table Screenshot at the bottom

This is the codes i try to use with laravel php

```
<tbody>
    @php $k=0; @endphp
    @foreach($maininformation as $inf)
    @php
        $dateTime = strtotime($inf->kapan);
        $dateNow = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $tesss = date("M j, Y H:i:s", strtotime($inf->kapan));
        $tanggals = date("M j, H:i:s", strtotime($inf->kapan));
        $diff = $dateTime - $dateNow;
        if($diff < 0){
            $show = "Expired";
        }else{
            $show = "";
        }
    if($show!="Expired"){ $k++;
    @endphp
    <script>
    $("td").each(function(){
        <?php echo "var theDate = '{$tesss}';"; ?>
        var countDownDate = new Date(theDate).getTime();
        var x = setInterval(function() {
                  var now = new Date().getTime();
                  var distance = countDownDate - now;
                  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                  <?php echo "var increments = '{$k}';"; ?>
                  var res = "demo"+increments;
                  document.getElementById(res).innerHTML = days + " Hari " + hours + " Jam "
                  + minutes + " Menit " + seconds + " Detik";
                }, 1000);
    });
    </script>
    <tr>
      <?php 
        $result = 'demo'.$k;
      ?>
        <td id="tableson" style="text-align: center;">{{$k}}</td>
        <td id="tableson" style="text-align: center;">{{$inf->title}}</td>
        <td id="tableson" style="text-align: center;">{{$inf->information}}</td>
        <td>{{$tanggals}}<p id={{$result}}></p></td>
    </tr>
    @php } @endphp
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

i have already solved the loop issue but i dont know why my first row doesnt show the times ive do for the codes.

NOTES: im new to codes and try to do some logic so i can solve my problem so pls be kind to me (i just copy paste the jquery codes i got from internet and try to edit some of them to work like i want to do).

ive thinking about maybe different name variable caused the logic error, but why just the first row has empty value? ive try to add many row and delete some row, its working fine and just the first row has empty value.

this is the table i got:

[image: this is the table, and the red circle is the value i want to be filled.]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the laravel.log file?

Comment: In your php loop you should create a div with a proper class, then do foreach loop in jQuery somewhere else ;)

Comment: @OT413 my browser run normally when run my localhost. but im not sure how to  see if theres an error with laravel.log, im still new to laravel, so ill try to read and understand that. thanks for the respon

Comment: thank you for ur advice, i will try to learn how to make some beautiful code latter after i know some basic of codes. @NorbertJurga

Comment: Do you see any errors in the your browser's console? https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console